# NetSuite Rest Web Services Query Transaction and Transaction Lines Tables

Tags: jquery, transactions, postman, netsuite

Curious how I can query the transactions and transaction_lines tables using rest Web Services?

I have varied queries working in postman like:

`{"q": "SELECT * FROM transaction t WHERE createddate >= '6/1/2021'"}`

But so far I am not able to to connect to the transaction_lines table and get the error:

`{"q": "SELECT * FROM transaction_lines WHERE date_created >= '1/1/2021'"}`

error...

Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Invalid search type: transaction_lines

I am looking at these links but do not see a way to query the transaction_lines table?

[REST_API_Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2021.1/index.html)

these are for the
[odbc tables](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/odbc/record/customer.html)

Thanks Much for your help,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

The query for transaction_lines is wrong since you might not have "Date created" field at the transaction line level. You need to do a join between "Transaction" and "Transaction_Lines" table. Please see the below query for joining both the tables using Date_created condition as you require. I have just selected top 1. You can later replace it with "*"

```
Select top 1 TRANSACTION_LINES.tranid, TRANSACTIONS.tranid
FROM TRANSACTIONS
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_LINES ON TRANSACTION_LINES.TRANSACTION_ID = TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_ID
WHERE TRANSACTIONS.DATE_CREATED = '6/1/2021';
```

Please try this query and let me know how this goes!! All the best :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your query looks very good - however I think that the rest api does not allow joins. when I try something simple like ```{"q": "SELECT * FROM transaction_lines"}``` (limit 5) it always errors like: Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Invalid search type: transaction_lines. is the transaction_lines table available in the rest api?

Comment: The query operation is used to execute a query on a specific record type based on a set of criteria.Record query only returns record IDs and HATEOAS links. That is, query results have a form of non-expanded references. Additionally, you can only use body fields in query conditions. Saved queries, multilevel joins, and sublist and subrecord queries are not supported. So based on above, I don't think "Transaction_lines" table is available through REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

The table name for the REST api is `transactionline` not `transaction_lines`.  You can view the available tables / columns here:  https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/analytics/record/transactionLine.html

The rest api exposes the v2.0 analytics schema, not the v1.0 connect schema.

Comment: Sorry i was late with this - THANKS VERY MUCH!

Comment: I use the same link to query the tables but for example: accounts give me the same error `Invalid search query`.